# Is possible to eliminate a column of a list of lists if some value is present

Tags: python, list

I am having a problem with list of lists. I want to know if there is a way to eliminate a column if some value is present
Example:

```
List = [[1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1],
        [2, 2, 2, 4, 2, 2, 2],
        [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]]
```

if the number 4 is present in the list of lists eliminate that column giving for result:

```
Result_List = [[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
               [2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2],
               [3, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 3]]
```

Due to 4 is present in List[0][1],List[1][3],List[0][5]
Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
lst = [[1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1], 
       [2, 2, 2, 4, 2, 2, 2], 
       [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]]

out = list(
    map(
        list,
        zip(
            *(
                [0] * len(lst) if any(v == 4 for v in c) else c
                for c in zip(*lst)
            )
        ),
    )
)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1], 
 [2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2], 
 [3, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 3]]
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try with your solution

Answer (score 1):

First transpose your list with `zip` and `*` so it becomes a list of columns:

```
>>> my_list = [[1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1],
...         [2, 2, 2, 4, 2, 2, 2],
...         [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]]
>>> [z for z in zip(*my_list)]
[(1, 2, 3), (4, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 4, 3), (1, 2, 3), (4, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3)]
```

Then you can replace columns containing 4 with 0s:

```
>>> [[0 for _ in z] if 4 in z else z for z in zip(*my_list)]
[(1, 2, 3), [0, 0, 0], (1, 2, 3), [0, 0, 0], (1, 2, 3), [0, 0, 0], (1, 2, 3)]
```

and then transpose it back using the same `zip(*(...))` trick:

```
>>> [list(z) for z in zip(*([0 for _ in z] if 4 in z else z for z in zip(*my_list)))]
[[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1], [2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2], [3, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 3]]
```